# Why mat-option text is not rendering in view sometimes?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I have a form where there is a mat-select field. The mat-select field will show value even if the option doesn't match the list of options. Please take a reference of this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-37vakn?file=src/app/app.component.html).

In this example, on button click, I am adding a value in a form that doesn't match with theJSON values. The same thing I have implemented is working only on the initial page load but not on another button click. The `get` function is though returning `true` but in view, I cannot see the text in option.

**component.ts**

```
xyz = [
  { id: 'a', value: 'a'},
  { id: 'b', value: 'b'},
  { id: 'c', value: 'c'}
];
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

form = this.fb.group({
  field1: ['a']
});

get deletedValue() {
  return this.xyz.map(x => x.value).indexOf(this.form.value.field1)<0
  && this.form.value.field1 !== '';
}

action() {
  this.form.patchValue({
    field1: 'z'
  });
}
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select formControlName="field1">
    <option *ngIf="deletedValue" class="d-none" [value]="form.get('field1').value">
                    {{ form.get('field1').value }}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let i of xyz" [value]="i.value">{{i.value}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<button (click)="action()">Click</button>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: your component is in call method ngOnInit() ?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you

Comment: Is your problem with `mat-select` or `select`?

Comment: @David it's on ```mat-select```

Comment: I'm confused then, your stackblitz shows a basic select. Do you get the same behaviour as in the stackblitz?

Comment: Mark as right If my solution is worked properly

Comment: @AmanGojariya yup actually I didn't try yet but looking at it looks like it will work

Comment: Okay try it. I have try in stackblitz it was worked for me

Comment: @AmanGojariya thanks this somehow helped me for the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add this code in your **component.ts** in action function

```
action() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      field1: 'z'
    });
    this.xyz.push({id: this.form.controls['field1'].value, value: this.form.controls['field1'].value})
}
```

Then it will add the 'z' value in your dropdown option.